# Embed AngularJS app and run on on WebBrowser control in C# desktop app

Tags: c#, angularjs

I have developed single page web app using AngularJS and deployed on the web server.

However I want to run standalone version of the app on windows, so I'm trying to embed the web app completely into desktop app and load/run it on the desktop without internet connection.

Any advise will be appreciated.